# Should I use C# or C++ for desktop

Tags: c++, c#

My question is what language is more usefull for desktop development for example to do a windows program

I come from python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows, the best way is C# and VB, C++ is fine but it's hard core way.
If you want to write a cross platform C++ is better than C#.